# how to set the option of select dynamically via angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, model

I found many question regarding to this topic and solutions to can not help; I have select like

```
   <select type="text" id="role" name="role" ng-model="role" ng-options="rol as rol.title for rol in rolelist" class="form-control" required>
        <option value="">Select Role</option>
    </select>
    <p class="ng-invalid"  ng-show="addForm.role.$error.required">Role need to selected</p>
```

and want to set the value of role model via angular js; i have done like this;

```
 $scope.role=$json.data.role_id;
```

didnot work for me?

Answer (score 2):

ngOptions uses an expression to define what ngModel will be bound to.  Since you have defined it as:

```
ng-options="rol as rol.title for rol in rolelist"
```

You are binding ngModel to a rol. Try this:

```
$scope.role=$json.data
```